# Why does my FrameLayout structure changes when using different android version

Tags: android, android-layout, android-framelayout

Why my FrameLayout structure differs between android version 7-13 and 14-17? The TableLayout moves up if used with android version 14-17.

The Layout is my crude attemp to make a analog clock with 2 chrono and Date function. I tried to upload a picture but I do not have enough REPUTATION to upload one.

What's d remedy 4 this 1? Thanks!!!!!!!!!!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:id="@+id/widget34"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/Table"
        android:layout_width="152dp"
        android:layout_height="111dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/Tablerow"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <AnalogClock
                android:id="@+id/AnalogClock1"
                android:layout_width="44dp"
                android:layout_height="44dp"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#000000" />

            <AnalogClock
                android:id="@+id/widget35"
                android:layout_width="44dp"
                android:layout_height="44dp"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#000000" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/date"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_marginLeft="21dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:paddingLeft="2dp"
                android:paddingRight="2dp"
                android:text="some txt"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    <AnalogClock
        android:id="@+id/AnalogClock01"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_gravity="top"
       android:dial="@drawable/dialg" />

  </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now this Layout is stable through all Android version. Maybe the problem with my initial layout is the TableLayout.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/widget32"
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_height="280dp"
    android:background="@drawable/dial_01" >

  <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/Table"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="120dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <AnalogClock
            android:id="@+id/AnalogClock1"
            android:layout_width="44dp"
            android:layout_height="44dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hand_hour="@drawable/invictus"
            android:hand_minute="@drawable/hourc2" />

        <AnalogClock
            android:id="@+id/widget35"
            android:layout_width="44dp"
            android:layout_height="44dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hand_hour="@drawable/hourc2"
            android:hand_minute="@drawable/invictus" />
     </LinearLayout>

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/background"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:paddingRight="2dp"
        android:text="Wed 01"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
  </FrameLayout>

  <AnalogClock
    android:id="@+id/AnalogClock01"
  android:layout_width="280dp"
  android:layout_height="280dp" />
```

<  /FrameLayout>